# Why is there private_html in my [cms.root] directory variable and is it trouble?

Tags: installation, civicrm.settings.php, directory

The *Settings - Upload Directories* screen (url `civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1`) makes it possible to examine the value of the `[cms.root]` variable. Just click the first help question mark.

In my case the `cms.root` path contains the directory `private_html`. That is a bit strange because I installed CiviCRM in the `public_html` directory and also added this path to the `$civicrm_root` variable.

Why is this, and does it harm?

More details: The CiviCRM version is 4.7.27 on Drupal. It runs on a VPS administered with DirectAdmin, and https is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It starts with a peculiarity of DirectAdmin. Using a subdomain, you have to upload the files for **https** connection to `private_html` and the files for not secure **http** connection to `public_html`. For the situation these files are the same DirectAdmin offers the option to create a  symbolic link from `private_html` to `public_html`. Thus when you ask for `https://<domain>/file.html` it looks for the file `/private_html/file.html` and thanks to the link this is the same as `public_html/file.html`.

The `[cms.root]` variabele is not set. It is derived from the `DRUPAL_ROOT` constant, that is calculated with `getcwd()`. At the moment you use a secure connection this functions returns the `private_html` directory.

And it causes trouble.

The directory variable  `[cms.root]` is used to calculate the URL variabele `[civicrm.root]` so this is also wrong. The effect is that a lot of javascript files are not found, for example `ckeditor.js`.

My solution is adding the `[cms.root]` directly to the `civicrm.settings.php` file with the following line:

```
$civicrm_paths['cms.root']['path'] = '/home/<user>/domains/<subdomain>/public_html/crm';
```