# Fix For "Incorrect Resource URL" Not Working

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, settings

I am getting the error "Incorrect Resource URL" and seeing 404 for URLs that go to "undefinedjs/jquery/jquery.crmAjaxTable.js" and many instances of the error "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."

I have tried resetting the URL (/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1), adding a static path (civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1) and doing an override (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/).

I am seeing the error in the UI and viewing the 404 using the browser console.  I am also using the CV command from the command line and see that the generated path from  (/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1) does not match what I would expect.

[root@domain default]# cv path -c userFrameworkResourceURL
https://crm.domian.org//home/user/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm

I think the URL should be https://crm.domian.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm.

This started when upgrading a Drupal 7 site to 4.7.28.

Help with this is greatly appreciated. I am out of ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar strange problem, and it had to do with symbolic links in unix. Q & A in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21814/why-is-there-private-html-in-my-cms-root-directory-variable-and-is-it-trouble/21815#21815 .

Comment: I tried this and it sounds like it would be the answer but it is not working the way I am understanding it.  I am seeing no change just adding this line to the CiviCRM settings file.  Is there a specific place this should be added.  Is there a variable that needs to be initialized?

Comment: Sorry this went in two comments but with this variable defied I get no results for cv path -d '[civicrm.root]' or  cv path -d '[cms.root]'. Thanks, Josh!

Answer (score 4):

We've had basic authentication active on the installation which broke the check. After adding the server IP to the whitelist the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this on my site by setting allow_url_fopen to "on" in php settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, which came down to the `l10n.js` file not being created correctly.  To troubleshoot this, I:

- Opened my browser's Developer Tools (by pressing F12);
- Went to the "Network" tab and filtered by "JS";
- Found the file that had my current language in the name (see screenshot - in this case, "en_US").
- Right-clicked the name and selected "Open in New Tab".

I saw an error message, which I was able to troubleshoot more directly.

For folks upgrading to Civi 5.3.x using multilingual, you're likely to encounter the same problem.  The trick is to rebuild the multilingual schema.  I did this with `drush cvapi system.rebuildmultilingualschema`, comparable commands exist for WordPress etc.

I figured this out because my images weren't loading, which I saw used the value `CRM.config.resourceBase` which [this forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=34221.0.html) told me was set in the `l10njs/<language>` file.